# Usage of ADA GPS with GtkAda

Tags: ide, gtk, ada

I am trying to use GtkAda with GNAT Programming Studio. When I load the standard template for a simple GUI program, I get the following errors:

"gtk.ads" not found

I tried to add the following (as the mentioned file itself recommends in its comments):

with "gtkada";

or this one...

with "/usr/share/ada/adainclude/gtkada.gpr";

but I get the error message:

main.adb:1:06: identifier expected

How can I make it compile and how can I use GPS with GtkAda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtkada.gpr`is a **project** file (*.gpr), and your **program** files (*.ads, *.adb) can only import other program files, not project files. Those `with` statements should go in your project file.

Comment: You are right, I changed my project files in the following way: GPS->Project Window (project tree)->Right click on my project->Project submenu->Edit source file (if there is a more general way to do this, please let me know). I added _with "with "/usr/share/ada/adainclude/gtkada.gpr";"_

Comment: That should have been just `with "/usr/share/ada/adainclude/gtkada.gpr”;`, not *with “with ...*

Comment: @user1724641: You could also do GPS->Project Window (project tree)->Right click on my project->Project submenu->Dependencies

Comment: Simon Wright: I meant this: I have added GtkAda with the expression `with "/usr/share/ada/adainclude/gtkada.gpr";`